# Type 'Article | null' is not assignable to type 'void'

Tags: typescript, repository-pattern, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I am trying to implement an interface into a class using typescript.

This is my class:

```
import connector from '../../../../common/mysql.persistence'
import { Article } from '../../domain/article'
import { ArticleRepository } from '../../article.repository'

export class ArticleMySQLRepository implements ArticleRepository {
  public async all(): Promise<Article[]> {
    const [rows] = await connector.execute(
      'SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC'
    )

    return rows as Article[]
  }

  public async find(id: Number): Promise<Article | null> {
    const [rows]: any[] = await connector.execute(
      'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?',
      [id]
    )

    if (rows.length) {
      return rows[0] as Article
    }

    return null
  }

  public async store(entry: Article): Promise<void> {
    const date = new Date()
    const likes:number = 0
    const shares:number = 0
    
    await connector.execute(
      'INSERT INTO article(id, title, slug, description, content, likes, shares, updatedAt, createdAt) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [entry.id, entry.title, entry.slug, entry.description, entry.content, likes, shares, null, date ]
    )
  }

  public async update(entry: Article): Promise<void> {
    const date = new Date()

    await connector.execute(
      'UPDATE article SET title = ?, slug = ?, description = ?, content = ?, updatedAt = ? WHERE id = ?',
      [entry.title, entry.slug, entry.description, entry.content, date, entry.id]
    )
  }

  public async remove (id: Number): Promise<void> {
    await connector.execute(
        'DELETE FROM article WHERE id = ?',
        [id]
      )
  }
}
```

Then my interface:

```
import { Article } from './domain/article'

export interface ArticleRepository {
  all(): Promise<Article[]>
  find(id: Number):Promise<Article | null>
  store(entry: Article):Promise<void>
  update(entry: Article):Promise<void>
  find(id: Number): Promise<void>
}
```

I need to follow that interface for any other repository I want to implement. By the way, the editor is showing this error in the find method:

> Property 'find' in type 'ArticleMySQLRepository' is not assignable to
> the same property in base type 'ArticleRepository'.   Type '(id:
> Number) => Promise<Article | null>' is not assignable to type '{ (id:
> Number): Promise<Article | null>; (id: Number): Promise; }'.
> Type 'Promise<Article | null>' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
> Type 'Article | null' is not assignable to type 'void'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void'.t

Is there any setting I need to change on my tsconfig?

Comment: As dumb as it sounds, try restarting your IDE. Somehow it's seeing your `find` method as a weird callable object type with two call signatures, even though you've never defined that. Very strange.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs following your recommendation I restart the IDE and I continue with the problem. It's a typescript error, because I get the same error running ts-node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I didn't spot it at first, but your interface defines `find()` twice:

```js
export interface ArticleRepository {
  all(): Promise<Article[]>
  find(id: Number):Promise<Article | null> // defined here
  store(entry: Article):Promise<void>
  update(entry: Article):Promise<void>
  find(id: Number): Promise<void> // defined here
}
```

You probably want to get rid of the last one.

Comment: You right. The second one supposed to be the remove method. Thanks.